# Get Values from a column with different values in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find rows with same Number but different Value, I arrived to this query:

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE (Number INT, Value int )
INSERT @Table1 VALUES (32, 3)
INSERT @Table1 VALUES (32, 5)
INSERT @Table1 VALUES (45, 5)
INSERT @Table1 VALUES (45, 5)

SELECT DISTINCT Number, COUNT(Value)
FROM @Table1 GROUP BY Number, Value
HAVING COUNT(Value) < 2
```

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your query return expected results?   I usually see it written like this:

```
SELECT Number, COUNT(DISTINCT Value)
FROM @Table1 GROUP BY Number
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value) < 2
```

Or, based on your comment below, you could do this:

```
SELECT Number
FROM @Table1 a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Table1 b WHERE a.Number=b.Number and a.Value<>b.Value)
```

Comment: This should actually give you more closer to what you want than my answer.

Comment: I just want to know if I have same Number with different Value, don't need to return anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Number, COUNT(distinct Value) as value
FROM @Table1 GROUP BY Number
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join.

For a join:

```
  SELECT t1.Number, t1.Value
  FROM @Table1 t1
  JOIN @Table1 t2
  ON t2.Number = t1.Number 
    AND t2.Value <> t1.Value
```

This should get you on your way. You can use this as a sub-query if you want to have more presentable final result-set.